How to perform a Boolean AND search with TNTSearch?
By default searching cats dogs with TNTSearch shows all results that contain either cats OR dogs.
However, I would like to get only the results that contain both search terms provided.
What I tried:

cats AND dogs
cats & dogs
(cats dogs)
+cats +dogs

None of the queries above does a boolean AND search.
What is the correct query for TNTSearch?

https://github.com/teamtnt/tntsearch#boolean-search ?

As I wrote in the question, (cats dogs) does not work.

So you're saying that the documentation is wrong, and that (cats dogs) does an OR search, instead of AND (it's documented that it does an AND search)? Have you raised an issue on github with the maintainer of the library? And are you completely certain of that? It seems like a bit of a fundamental flaw which someone would have noticed before now. Can you provide a [mre] in the question here?

https://github.com/teamtnt/tntsearch/issues/314 Example (such as jsfiddle) is difficult, because the PHP script runs on a local server.

It doesn't need to be a runnable example, but as per [ask] and the on-topic guidance you are expected to provide a [mre] including relevant code and sample data within your question, not just in external links. You have more than enough reputation points to be already aware of that.

You didn't mention though if you were using ->search() or if you also tried ->searchBoolean()

OMG. Thanks a lot. This was the problem why it did not work!

That's why you were given the link https://github.com/teamtnt/tntsearch?tab=readme-ov-file#boolean-search earlier . Glad you've got it working.
